# bin/magento setup:upgrade not running

Tags: magento2, database, error, cli

I am facing a long lasting issue on this command

> - bin/magento setup:upgrade

I have made an extension hello world on magento2 stable version, which will simply print hello world on screen.

The thing is when I ran that....it gave me setup version, not specified error (though I have specified)...then I searched & ran this command -

> bin/magento setup:upgrade

When I ran above command then I met with another error....pdo_mysql is not installed....

Then I solved that error with the following commands:
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
sudo apt-get install pdo-mysql

then by doing php -m I could see the pdo_mysql in extensions list :)

But then as ran that command (bin/magento setup:upgrade) again....I got another error (very frustrated). Please check the attachment.

For solving that error I referred this one.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990708/error-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run-mysqld-mysq

I typed this: sudo find / -type s
so I got the list in that one of the line is like this......
**/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock**

now in that article, it says......"Once you find where the socket is being opened, add or edit the line to your /etc/my.cnf file with the path to the socket file".........so I opened /etc/my.cnf but....I found that the line is already there.....socket = /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock

Then it says to run this : kill -9 4969 or pkill -9 mysqld but I did not run...I am afraid it can cause damage to xampp...

Then it says....."After you do this you might want to look for a pid file in /var/run/mysqld/ and delete it" but the thing is I can not find mysqld folder inside var/run/ so I am confused what to do now....

Many times I restarted xampp by first stopping apache like this:
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop

But could not resolve the issue...

Can anyone please give the correct solution?

Magento 2 becomes a big problem running in Ubuntu for me :)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer given by Santosh Kumar & Denish Vachhani is absolutely right so I again say thank you to both of them :)

Now the thing is Santosh Kumar said search for mysqld.sock file using this command : find -name "mysqld.sock" I did it but no result found so it was unclear that how & from where can I have mysqld.sock file.

So finally what I did is :-

Before doing the following procedure please give your entire magento directory & sub directories & files the permission - 777 (in case of local or development phase)

Me gone to opt/lampp/var/mysql & looked for mysql.sock (remember that there wasn't available mysqld.sock file in my case) then I right clicked on it & selected "Make Link" so another file created from mysql.sock file so just renamed it to mysqld.sock & moved it (cut paste) to (outside opt folder)var/run/mysqld/ folder. If you don't find mysqld folder then simply create it. Remember that file should be having 777 permission.

Then go to your magento folder in terminal & hit this command :-
sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade & you will get success :)

Then visit your module from url & it will work :)

One note :- If you don't have mysqld directory in (outside opt folder)var/run then if you are not interested in making manually then here are the commands:

sudo mkdir /var/run/mysqld (this will make directory)

sudo mv /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysqld.sock /var/run/mysqld (this will move your created mysqld.sock file to var/run/mysqld)

this command from your magento folder in terminal - sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Few more tips :-
1) If you want to see how many commands you can hit then do this :-
Go to your magento folder in terminal then,

> cd bin
>   ./magento
>   You will have a list of commands :)

2) If you want to reindex then, go to your magento folder in terminal then hit these commands :-

> cd bin
>   ./magento indexer:reindex

3) If you want to compile then, go to your magento folder in terminal then hit these commands :-

> cd bin
>   ./magento setup:di:compile

Thank you & Good Luck

Comment: Hello, I am facing a problem while copying mysql.sock. "right clicked on it & selected "Make Link" so another file created from mysql.sock" this line didn't work for me. So I tried to copy by command line and getting following error.
 

`cp: cannot stat 'mysql.sock': No such file or directory`

Do you have any idea about this?

Answer (score 3):

search mysqld.sock
you can search it using command : find -name "mysqld.sock"
then right click on it and copy link 
then paste it under /var/run/mysqld/ and rename it to mysqld.sock
if there is no directory name "mysqld" in /var/run/ then create it

Comment: Hi Santosh, Thanks for your reply :) Now the thing is.....till now I already hit many commands so now if I fire this command...."sudo service apache2 start" it is not getting started....it is saying....AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably...bla bla bla.... :) so I hit this command....sudo apt-get upgrade php-mysql....it took 2 3 hours :( & finally done with a few errors (very less though but with errors) & when I hit find -name "mysqld.sock".....after printing 4 5 lines it was hanged up...very frustrated...but your solution looks close so will definitely come back to you :)

Comment: Hi Santosh, me tried hitting your given command like this :
nteam@nteam-System-Product-Name:~$ find -name "mysqld.sock"
but outcome coming like following :
find: `./.dbus': Permission denied
find: `./.gvfs': Permission denied
find: `./.cache/dconf': Permission denied

Any idea what to do now? as no specific path coming.

Comment: run command su and then enter root password,then after run same command..

Comment: Hi Santosh, I have fired the command like this.....
nteam@nteam-System-Product-Name:/$ sudo find -name "mysqld.sock"

It searched for 5 to 10 mins. but returned with no result :( so whole thing looked like this :-

nteam@nteam-System-Product-Name:/$ sudo find -name "mysqld.sock"
[sudo] password for nteam: 
nteam@nteam-System-Product-Name:/$

Answer (score 2):

please clear page_cache, view_process and di folder.

> please give sudo chmod -R 777 to root folder magento.

re-run compiler. using php -f bin/magento setup:di:compile

> and also give chmod 777 '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
>
> Note:- give full permission to magento root folder as well as mysqld.

Comment: Hi Denish, Thank you for your answer :) I am giving it a try right now & coming back to you.

Comment: Hi Denish, when I hit this command - php -f bin/...... then the following error coming.....

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20121212+lfs/pdo_mysql.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20121212+lfs/pdo_mysql.so: undefined symbol: pdo_parse_params in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20121212+lfs/pdo_mysqli.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20121212+lfs/pdo_mysqli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'PDO' already loaded in Unknown on line 0 then...

Comment: then compilation process started...then....it gave another error....Use of undefined constant MCRYPT_BLOWFISH - assumed 'MCRYPT_BLOWFISH'

Comment: if pdo error re generated please try **sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql** and please specify **MCRYPT_BLOWFISH** is your module name? than check code manually.

Comment: Hi Denish, nope...my extension/module name is Magento_Hello, ok yes so giving try to install mcrypt...& coming back. Thanks :)

Comment: please try this sudo ln -s /etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini /etc/php5/mods-available
sudo php5enmod mcrypt
sudo service apache2 restart

Comment: please find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19446679/mcrypt-not-present-after-ubuntu-upgrade-to-13-10

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33362/discussion-between-ka9-and-denish-vachhani).

Comment: sry i am in company now  so not possible to chat. i can only post comments.

Comment: Oh yes ok no issue....I can understand :) ok but will reply if some positive occurs :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the reason is I run the script "bin/magento setup:upgrade" under "root" account.

Need to switch to this account, and everything works fine:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

give chmod -R 777 /var/pub/app

This is due to the permission issue

Comment: Hi Ayush, thanks for you reply :) yes I am giving it a try & coming back to you....but I should inform you that I am getting an error in compilation of Mcrypt as I mentioned above :)

Comment: Hi Ayush, I could not find var/pub directory? where is it? in magento2 root folder var/pub? or in lampp?

Comment: yes pub in the magento root folder